How to get an effect of phantom read or fuzzy read under serializable isolation level in Oracle?
I know that there's is no phantom or non-repeatable read in serializable mode, but I received the task to obtain a similar effect with this level of isolation-during transaction 1, transaction 2 performs some actions that affect the results of the same query in transaction 1
I suppose it should be something with nulls-insert

Oracle does not apply read consistency to x$ "tables" (on which are built most v$ views), because they aren't actually tables, but calls to C programs. Only real data objects (like tables, indexes) can provide read consistency since they have ITL slots that can be used to rollback uncommitted changes to produce a consistent read (CR) block image.
So, if you want to affect transaction A1 to produce a non-repeatable-read (breaking read consistency) you could take an action in session B that affects the content of one of those v$ views:
Session B simply parsing a new cursor will change what A1 can see in x$kglcursor_child (v$sql), or logging out changes what A1 will see in x$ksuse (v$session). Or you can write/read to a file (utl_file) or an external proc any kind of possible inter-process communication you can think up that does not involve a table and can take place within the context of a single transaction.
